# jQuery - ordering divs in ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this code

```js
var $divs = $("div.product");

$('#priceAscending').on('click', function() {
 var ascendingOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).find("div.price").text() > $(b).find("div.price").text();
  });
  $("#container").html(ascendingOrderedDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  
  <button id="priceAscending">Price ascending</button>
  <!--<button id="priceDescending">Price descending</button>-->
  
  <div id="container">
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product One</span>
      <div class="price">14.85$</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Two</span>
      <div class="price">27.59$</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Three</span>
      <div class="price">2.64$</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I want to sort div.product in ascending order based on the price, but it doesn't work. It puts 2.64 in the middle but it should put it first.

How can I fix this issue using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `>` to `-`

```
return $(a).find("div.price").text() - $(b).find("div.price").text();
```

You also need to remove $ from price to compare the values. You can do it with `str.slice(0, -1)`

```
return $(a).find("div.price").text().slice(0, -1) - $(b).find("div.price").text().slice(0, -1);
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esdb92f6/2/)

Comment: Thanks for helping me and how about ordering descending?

Comment: Simply invert the logic. Instead of a - b, you do b - a. [Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/) you can find a lot of interesting ways to use `sort()` in JS.

Comment: What Mirakurun said is probably the best solution but what I like to do if I want some form of sorting switch is to add a `*-1` if it's descending which basically does the same but is easier to change conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the numeric value instead of the string

```js
var divs = $("div.product");

$('#priceAscending').on('click', function() {
 var ascendingOrderedDivs = divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aVal = parseFloat($(a).find("div.price").text().replace("$",""));
    var bVal = parseFloat($(b).find("div.price").text().replace("$",""));
   return aVal - bVal;
  });
  $("#container").html(ascendingOrderedDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  
  <button id="priceAscending">Price ascending</button>
  <!--<button id="priceDescending">Price descending</button>-->
  
  <div id="container">
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product One</span>
      <div class="price">14.85$</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Two</span>
      <div class="price">27.59$</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Three</span>
      <div class="price">2.64$</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `$` at the end of the prices with an empty string and use parseFloat to compare the values. Note that id's on the page should be unique. For all the spans you use `id="name`

```js
var $divs = $("div.product");

$('#priceAscending').on('click', function() {
  var ascendingOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat($(a).find("div.price").text().replace(/\$$/, '')) - parseFloat($(b).find("div.price").text().replace(/\$$/, ''));
  });
  $("#container").html(ascendingOrderedDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <button id="priceAscending">Price ascending</button>
  <!--<button id="priceDescending">Price descending</button>-->

  <div id="container">

    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product One</span>
      <div class="price">14.85$</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Two</span>
      <div class="price">27.59$</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product">
      <span id="name">Product Three</span>
      <div class="price">2.64$</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```